# Custom Break Command/Function with create_function() in PHP

Tags: php, loops, syntax, command

I'm wondering if it is possible in PHP to create a custom break command/function.

For example,

```
<?php
$custombreak = create_function('$a', 'if ($a == 3) break 1;');

$i = 0;
do {

    echo $i . '<br />';
    $i++;
    $custombreak($i);    //<-- I'd like to break the loop with a custom function.
    // if ($i==3)        //<-- this is not what I'm looking for
    //    break;      

} while ($i < 10);
?>
```

This is not valid PHP code but I hope you get what I'm trying to say. I'd like to escape the loop with the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way with Exceptions.

```
$i = 0;
try {
    do {
        $i++;
        echo $i . '<br />';
        custombreak($i);
    } while ($i <= 10);
} catch (Exception $e) {}

function custombreak($i) {
    if ($i > 3) throw new Exception("");
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you create normal function

```
function foo() {
  break 2; // this is not valid
}

while(true) {
  foo();
}
```

that doesn't work. This is what programmers do:

```
function foo() {
  return true;
}

while(true) {
  if(foo()) break;
}
```

So your code would be..

- http://codepad.org/lztnGflZ

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function control($a){
    if($a==3)
        return false;
    return true;
}

$i = 0;
do {

    echo $i . '<br />';
    $i++;    

} while ( ($i < 10) && (control($i)) );

?>
```

is it an answer for this question ?

Comment: No :D He asked about `break` not loop control :))

Comment: yep but you didn't answer why `break` command doesn't work :)) Question wasn't "how to make loop 0 to 3"

Comment: are you kidding me :) it's funny :) but i think he can use my opinion, i just give him a point for breaking loops. Just try to help. OK?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this control in while loop. Don't need to write a function i think.

```
<?php

$i = 0;
do {

    echo $i . '<br />';
    $i++;    

} while ( ($i < 10) && ($i!=3) );
?>
```

You know multiple controls don't you ?

Comment: This is not answer for the question.